# Data not loading after login / just after reshreshing page

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I got an simple login on my page. After logging in I'm displaying data from a server, that is just shown after refreshing the page once. 
Before I am getting an Error 500:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/getDesktop 500
angular.js:14800 Possibly unhandled rejection: ...
```

My AngularJS code is the following:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout){

//Username
$scope.user  = "";

//Desktop
$scope.storage = [];

//Get username

$http.get("/loggeduser", {transformResponse: function(response){
        return JSON.stringify(response);
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.user = response.data.substring(1, response.data.length-1);
});

//Show Desktop

    $http.get("/getDesktop").then(function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
           $scope.storage[i] = {name: response.data[i]};
       }           
       return;
   });
});
```

Backend:

```
//Returns Desktop
@GetMapping("/getDesktop")
public ArrayList<String> getDesktop() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();

    if(kdxF.getUser() != null) {
        itemNames = kdxF.showDesktop();  
        // Just a function to return the Elements in an ArrayList if Strings
        // If user is logged in
    }else {
        throw new Exception("Not logged in!");
    }

    return itemNames;
}
```

And I get the message "Not logged in"

Comment: `500` is server-side error, you need to show your backend code

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it with a kinda ugly solution, but it works.
I'm constantly checking if the user is null, then loading the data.

```
//Returns Desktop
@GetMapping("/getDesktop")
public ArrayList<String> getDesktop() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();
    int kill = 0; 

    while(kdxF.getUser() == null) {    // FIXME
        if(kill == 500) {
            break;
        }else {
            Thread.sleep(5);
            kill++;
        }
    }

    itemNames = kdxF.showDesktop();

    return itemNames;
}
```

If you get a better suggestion please tell me. :)